# filter on foreign and many to many relationship field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project. Here is an example of my model :

```
from django.db import models

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    handle = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    collections = models.ManyToManyField('Collection')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_id
```

I am trying to get all the `Brand_name` based on the value of the `Product.collection`

Eg: Shoes is a `Product.collection`, I want to get all the `Brand_name` for `collection` - shoes

I tried `__` method also. Somehow it is not working.

Comment: What is `'Collection'`? If you have a model `Collection` which say has an attribute `type` (CharField) then you can declare the many-to-many-field as `collections = models.ManyToManyField(Collection)` and you can filter for all `shoes` (assumed that a shoe is identified by `Collection.type == 'shoe'`) by doing `shoes = collections.filter(type='shoe')`. Or has the `Collection` a `Brand` and you want `Brand.name == 'shoe'` to be `True`? Your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
Brand.objects.product_set.filter(collections__name="Shoes").values('brand__name')
```

Comment: `Brand.objects.product_set.filter` will return a QuerySet for model `Product` but `Product` does not have an attribute `name` (as requested by `values('name')`). The `all` should be left out as well. I think @dreamer wants all `Brand.name` based on some attribute of `Product`.

Comment: You're right, then we can just replace 'name' by 'brand__name'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Brand.objects.filter(
    product__collection=product.collection
).values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

`product` is instance of `Product`.

Answer (score -1):

Add a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to your `foreign key` like below,

```
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, 
                          null=True, related_name='products')
```

And then you can try below query and it'll return you a `list` of all the `Brand.name` which has `product__collections_name='Shoes'`.

```
Brand.objects.filter(products__collections__name='Shoes').values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Probably a bit misleading if you choose `'brands'` as `related_name`, it should rather be `'products'` cause that's what it refers to.